# Prometheus metrics from recording rules

Tags: types, prometheus, metrics, rules, gauge

I have a simple question: when I write a rule in Prometheus, what is the type of the derived metric?
For example, if I have the following rule:

```
- record: derived_metric
  expr: increase(internal_metric[5m])
```

what is the type of "derived_metric"?
I assume that it is Gauge type.

Answer (score 2):

As indicated, in the [documentation](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/):

> The Prometheus client libraries offer four core metric types. These are currently only
> differentiated in the client libraries (to enable APIs tailored to the usage of the
> specific types) and in the wire protocol.
> **The Prometheus server does not yet make use of the type information and flattens all data into untyped time series**.

This means that for all purposes, metrics in Prometheus are untyped. The type is only used as a contract for some functions (like `increase()` expecting a `counter` input).

You are right that, if we had a more strongly typing system, you could write that the output of function `increase()` is of `gauge` type.